# How to verify a .md5sum file in snow leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, md5

In snow leopard there is program that can do md4 checksums.
How can I verifiy a .md5 file?

Comment: is there `md5`?  The two are interchangeable.

Comment: EXAMPLE: http://genunix.org/dist/windows/liveusb/OsolLiveUSB003.md5sum and i have to validate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simply:

```
port install cfv
```

and read the  manual

Comment: seeing someone answering his own questions and accepting them, after getting it spelled out nicely really pisses me off. Thanks dude, remind me not to help you any more.

Comment: Actually his answer is the best. cfv can create md5 and can also verify them. Why do manual comparing when I have a large set of files? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: would do the same seeing other people providing irrelevant answers

Answer (score 5):

In OSX, it's simply md5 or openssl md5

```
md5 /path/to/file
```

or

```
openssl md5 /path/to/file
```

Edit for clarification: You would then compare the output of the md5 command to the values in the .md5sum file to verify that the files are the same.

Comment: no, i ask how to check a .md5sum file, not how to generate it!

Comment: The contents of the MD5sum file are the md5 sum. You generate a sum on the file in question, and compare :-)

Comment: If you dont know, this is an md5sum file http://genunix.org/dist/windows/liveusb/OsolLiveUSB003.md5sum and i have to validate that

Comment: You would run "md5 OsolLiveUSB003-src.zip", and compare the output to the string of hex digits in the file, then do the same for the other filename. I edited the answer for clarification.

Comment: no, again it is a manual comparation, i cannot compare 50000 files by hand... for example..

Comment: It would have to be scripted. You could use the instructions here: http://solidstateraam.com/mac-os-x-replicating-md5sum-output-format/ to create a Linux/Unix-like md5sum output, and then use something to programmatically compare the files. I do not believe it is available as a native function in OSX at all, especially when you're trying to use a non-OSX formatted md5sum file.

Answer (score 5):

I see two ways for you,

1. one is easier and means installing additional software,
2. the other means writing a little script to automate the checksumming.

`1.` install GNU md5:

get macports for your system from http://www.macports.org and install the base package. Then, install the port "md5sha1sum", which has the option "-c" to read a file containing checksums and compare files to it.

or, `2.` do it with what you have:

I assume you have a MD5 checksum file of the form:

```
0fd81f886638a12ed9efe4fd8b44187d  dir1/dir2/file4
bc2a22d0fee688065ea19e44dae88e19  dir1/file3
fa9b969a22077e46131cdd6b602a208c  dir3/file5
5c4a2bdccf48c3e7bf7489f24ac5fcb1  file1
7e06cbbb761e90e2e059657927b43f5c  file2
```

(note that the separator are 2 spaces)

now, create new MD5 checksums locally with openssl, like:

`find * -type f | xargs openssl md5 >openssl-md5`

which will produce

```
MD5(dir1/dir2/file4)= 0fd81f886638a12ed9efe4fd8b44187d
MD5(dir1/file3)= bc2a22d0fee688065ea19e44dae88e19
MD5(dir3/file5)= fa9b969a22077e46131cdd6b602a208c
MD5(file1)= 5c4a2bdccf48c3e7bf7489f24ac5fcb1
MD5(file2)= 7e06cbbb761e90e2e059657927b43f5c
```

the output is different, but you can transmogrify that to match what GNU md5 makes:

`cat openssl-md5 | sed -e 's/^MD5(\(.*\))= \(.*\)/\2  \1/'`

```
0fd81f886638a12ed9efe4fd8b44187d  dir1/dir2/file4
bc2a22d0fee688065ea19e44dae88e19  dir1/file3
fa9b969a22077e46131cdd6b602a208c  dir3/file5
5c4a2bdccf48c3e7bf7489f24ac5fcb1  file1
7e06cbbb761e90e2e059657927b43f5c  file2
```

this gives you a checksum file to compare to the original checksum file. Do a diff and you're finished ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking for the program to *check* an md5sum file (not just generate one). I found the answer at https://raamdev.com/2008/howto-install-md5sum-sha1sum-on-mac-os-x/

#### Homebrew

`brew install md5sha1sum`

#### MacPorts

`sudo port install md5sha1sum`

#### Verify

Now that you have the typical `md5sum` program.

`md5sum -c *.md5sum`